# Performance testing of SFDC application

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am having trouble while replaying the script in loadrunner.
As in salesforce it ask for verification code. And the script is getting failed when it approaches the verification request, as it is asking for verification code.
Can any one suggest me what to do in such type of scenarios so that script is passed?
I need it now. Please reply as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your public IP into trusted network of salesforce. When you do that it will not ask for verification code.

Here are steps to do so:

1. Go to google and search what is my IP.
2. Copy the public IP given by google
3. Login into salesforce and go to setup
4. In quick search enter 'Network Access' click open Network Access link
5. Add the IP in trusted network and run your tool again.

More info: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_networkaccess.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the verification code by specifying the trusted ip range in Setup -> Admininstration Setup -> Security Controls -> Network Access.